apt update failing tracepath to canonical-group-limited.e0-50.switch1.bos2.he.net
my attempted updates are hanging retrieving headers.  It looks like routing stops at canonical-group-limited.e0-50.switch1.bos2.he.net
Anyone else having this issue?

root@t470:/etc/apt# curl -v http://archive.ubuntu.com/
*   Trying 91.189.91.82:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.82) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: archive.ubuntu.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
^C
root@t470:/etc/apt# curl -v http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
*   Trying 91.189.91.82:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.82) port 80 (#0)
> GET /ubuntu HTTP/1.1
> Host: archive.ubuntu.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
^C

root@t470:/etc/apt# tracepath -4 archive.ubuntu.com 
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  _gateway                                              2.934ms 
 1:  _gateway                                              3.037ms 
 2:  ip-136-228-110-1.static.oecfiber.com                  5.425ms 
 2:  ip-136-228-110-1.static.oecfiber.com                  6.519ms 
 3:  172.18.1.80                                           5.543ms 
 4:  kanc-b2-link.ip.twelve99.net                         12.571ms 
 5:  chi-bb2-link.ip.twelve99.net                         22.902ms asymm  7 
 6:  chi-bb2-link.ip.twelve99.net                         22.631ms asymm  7 
 7:  98.181.111.26                                        39.233ms 
 8:  100ge0-35.core2.bna1.he.net                          30.174ms 
 9:  port-channel4.core2.ind1.he.net                      33.305ms asymm 10 
10:  port-channel13.core2.chi1.he.net                     36.300ms asymm  9 
11:  100ge0-40.core2.bos1.he.net                          56.570ms asymm 12 
12:  port-channel1.core1.bos2.he.net                      59.583ms asymm 13 
13:  canonical-group-limited.e0-50.switch1.bos2.he.net    48.617ms asymm 11 
14:  no reply
15:  no reply
16:  no reply
17:  no reply
18:  no reply
19:  no reply
20:  no reply
^C

